# Deleting a linked list with specified data recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I want to delete a linked list recursively. I figured how to do this iteratively but I'm curious on how to do this. So far I have:

```
void deleteNodeRecursively(LinkedList *list, int value){
  Node *curr=list->head;
  if (list->head==NULL){
    return;
  }

  else if (list->head->data==value){
    Node *x=list->head->next;
    delete list->head;
    list->head=x;
  }
   else{
    LinkedList *newlist;
    newlist->head=list->head->next;
    deleteNodeRecursively(newlist,value);
  }
}
```

Where I defined

```
struct LinkedList{
   Node *head;
};

struct Node{
   int data;
   Node *next;
};
```

I can remove the head if need be, but I can't figure out how to remove the body or tails and then correctly stitch up the list, let alone do it recursively. How do I proceed? Why won't this work?

EDIT: Removed question marks and replaced with code that I thought would work.

Comment: First, you need a recursive algorithm, then a function to match. Hint: it will likely take a `Node **` and `int` arguments.

Comment: Where you have question marks why can't you put deleteNodeRecursively(&list, value) and eventually it should return when null? Looks like you have the base case and the "all other cases", just need to keep calling it now

Comment: Surely I can't do that since just recalling my function would check the same head node over and over again.

Comment: U r deleting the "head" every time, and changing it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a *"correct"*  constructor and destructor for your *Node* data.

You would have to track address of the deletion, for which you could pass a double pointer or a reference to pointer.

```
void deleteNodeRecursively(Node** list, int value){
//                             ^^^ double pointer to track address withing recursive call
  Node *curr= *list ; 
  if (curr ==NULL){ // Base case for recursion 
    return;
  }

  else if ( curr->data==value){ // If node to be deleted is found
    *list = curr->next; // Update the address for recursive calls
    delete curr; // Delete this current "got" node
  }

 // Else simple recurse into 
  deleteNodeRecursively( &(*list)->next, value );
}
```

Note: This implementation will delete all nodes with *data* that matches *value* .

Comment: Agreed, as simple as that.

Comment: How could this be implemented if I have a curr->head? Wouldn't I have to keep track of what the 'head' is?

Comment: @AyumuKasugano You have to pass the starting node to `deleteNodeRecursively` which would in most cases will be the _`root`_ / _`head`_ node

Comment: Ah I see. Is there any other way to do this without calling the function on the head node (eg calling the entire list?) without removing the curr->head feature

Comment: it is possible, since you didn't provide your `LinkedList` definition its hard to assume things. And now its too late to provide one ;) . Should be pretty much similar